# nginx ingress controller not able to connect with websockets

Tags: websocket, nginx-ingress

I am trying to make a connection with websockets and I am using nginx ingress controller using helm. when i am accessing the application using abc.com it is not able to make the websocket connection and always says that the connection is closed.

Could anyone has got any experience around this, any other config i need to make.

My deployment.yaml looks like below -

```html
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: creditlibraryui
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    app: creditlibraryui
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 3000
    name: http
  selector:
    app: creditlibraryui
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: creditlibraryui-v1
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: creditlibraryui
        version: v1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: creditlibraryui
        image: abc/creditlibraryui:0.0.1
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
          name: http
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: creditlibraryservice
  labels:
    app: creditlibraryservice
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8102
    name: http
  selector:
    app: creditlibraryservice
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: creditlibraryservice-v1
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: creditlibraryservice
        version: v1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: creditlibraryservice
        image: abc/creditlibraryservice:0.0.1
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8102
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: creditlibrarydb
  labels:
    app: creditlibrarydb
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 27017
    name: http
  selector:
    app: creditlibrarydb
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: creditlibrarydb-v1
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: creditlibrarydb
        version: v1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: creditlibrarydb
        image: mongo:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 27017
```

And my ingress.yaml looks like -

```html
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: creditlibrary-ingress
  namespace : kube-system
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    certmanager.k8s.io/acme-challenge-type: dns01
    certmanager.k8s.io/acme-dns01-provider: cloudflare
    certmanager.k8s.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-staging
    nginx.org/websocket-services: "creditlibraryui,creditlibraryservice"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: abc.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: "/"
        backend:
          serviceName: creditlibraryui
          servicePort: 3000
      - path: "/api"
        backend:
          serviceName: creditlibraryservice
          servicePort: 8102
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - "abc.com"
    secretName: abc-tls
```

Comment: You tried to access it on port 3000?

Comment: yes i tried all those options, thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue by adding another path for websocket in my ingress, like below -

```html
  rules:
  - host: abc.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: "/"
        backend:
          serviceName: creditlibraryui
          servicePort: 3000
      - path: "/api"
        backend:
          serviceName: creditlibraryservice
          servicePort: 8102
      - path: "/ws"
        backend:
          serviceName: creditlibraryservice
          servicePort: 8102
```

Answer (score 0):

After spending 2 days trying to figure out why I'm getting 426 http error code for socket connections, I reaalised that proxy upgrade headers are required in the nignxserver block to upgrade websocket connections.

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippets: |
  location / {
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
```

To anyone having 426 http error code issues with websockets and nginx ingress controller(kubernetes maintained), you can try this gist that I created
https://gist.github.com/acidbotmaker/4b356e68d39dd46fa92537ab2ffea842