# Error connecting to websocket server with minikube NGINX ingress

Tags: kubernetes, socket.io, minikube, nginx-ingress

My question is very similar to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57642650/websocket-connection-in-kubernetes-cluster-with-nginx-ingress). I am trying to access a socket server with NGINX ingress in minikube. I am not sure if different annotations are still necessary for cluster v1.22.2, as described [here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/miscellaneous/#websockets), but I tried adding them as described in various stackoverflow [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53770981/using-socket-io-on-gke-with-nginx-ingress) and attempted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58697950/kubernetes-nginx-ingress-and-socket-io-connection-issues) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54163642/nginx-ingress-controller-not-able-to-connect-with-websockets), but none worked for me.

Although it works fine when I forward the service port, I am getting error when I am trying to access it with ingress.

```
*WebSocket connection to 'ws://textchess.com/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket' failed:*
```

The `driver\etc\host` file has minikube's ip as textchess.com

**index.js**

```js
const express = require("express");
const { createServer } = require("http");
const { Server } = require("socket.io");

const app = express();
const httpServer = createServer(app);
const io = new Server(httpServer, {
  cors: {
    origin: "*",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
  },
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {

  console.log("connection established");

  socket.on("client_emit", (arg) => {
    socket.emit("server_emit", arg);
  });
});

httpServer.listen(3000);
```

**Deployment/ClusterIP service**

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: socket-deployment
  labels:
    app: socket
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: socket
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: socket
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: socket
          image: socket

---
# clusterIP service
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: socket-srvc
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: socket
  ports:
    - name: socket-port
      protocol: TCP
      port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
```

**ingress**

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-test
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.org/websocket-services: "socket-srvc"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: textchess.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /test
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: socket-srvc
                port:
                  number: 3000

          - path: /socket.io/.*
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: socket-srvc
                port:
                  number: 3000

  ingressClassName: nginx

---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: IngressClass
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  controller: k8s.io/ingress-nginx
```

**client**

```js
<script>
  // const socket = io("http://localhost:3000", { transports: ["websocket"] });

  const socket = io("http://textchess.com:/test", {
    reconnection: true,
    transports: ["websocket"],
  });

  socket.on("server_emit", (args) => {
    console.log(args);
  });
  document.getElementById("event_emitter").onclick = function changeContent() {
    var d = new Date();
    var time = d.toLocaleTimeString();
    socket.emit("client_emit", time);
  };
</script>
```

Comment: Did you find any solutions?